# Изменение иконки кнопки с помощью триггера при использовании MVVM

Tags: wpf, триггер

Начал разбираться с триггерами. И появилась идея сделать так, чтобы кнопка пуска меняла свою картинку на паузу и наоборот

[image]

Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку, если не запущено, то меняем на иконку паузы, а если запущено меняем на иконку запустить.

Я могу это сделать без триггеров, так как я использую MVVM, можно просто сделать меня значение иконки в свойстве, но мне кажется это не правильным подходом (потому что, как я понял, это и есть задача триггеров). Да и элементов пуск/пауза у меня в окне не один а несколько, и делать под каждое свой свойство во ViewModel не очень правильно (опять же на мой взгляд).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во вью-модели у вас должно быть свойство `IsPlaying` или вроде того. Явные иконки в виде картинок или даже идентификаторов ресурсов нежелательны.

А вот как во вьюхе превратить булево свойство в иконку — это уже на выбор, существует множество способов. Можно задать для кнопки иконку по умолчанию и добавить триггер, который при другом значении изменит иконку.

Я предпочитаю делать конвертер `DictionaryConverter : IValueConverter`, класть в него маппинг между входным булевым значением и выходной картинкой, а затем делать простой биндинг с конвертером — так меньше кода.

Comment: Спасибо, как то я не подумал о конвертерах.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем.

С точки зрения архитектуры приложения, задача триггеров — изменять визуальные аспекты контролов. Пример: когда над контролом мышка, поменять цвет фона.

Вы хотите, однако, поменять предназначение кнопки. У вас не просто поменялся визуальный аспект, у вас поменялся смысл кнопки. Для этого правильным архитектурным решением будет подмена всей кнопки на другую (при помощи стандартных для MVVM методов). Даже если триггер и *можно* технически <s>натянуть на глобус</s> заставить делать то, что вам нужно, это неправильный путь.

Comment: Что неправильного в кнопке `PlayPauseButton`? Можно, конечно, заняться заменой кнопок, но это зависит от предпочтений.

Comment: У кнопки я хочу понять только иконку через триггеры и больше ничего, а Command останется прежним. Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: @Discord: Потому что она тогда (вместе со своей VM) выполняет _две_ задачи. Это вдвое больше, чем нужно.

Comment: @VladD Ну вот кнопка "Пуск" сколько задач выполняет? Она ведь 1) открывает меню, 2) скрывает меню. Нужно переключать команды? %)

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Вы обманываете себя. Вы хотите поменять **смысл** кнопки с «включить воспроизведение» на «выключить воспроизведение». Это две _разные_ кнопки. И именно поэтому вам и захотелось, чтобы они и _выглядели_ по-разному.

Comment: @VladD И вообще, нажатый "Пуск" и ненажатый "Пуск" — это совсем разные вещи! Они даже выглядят по-разному!

Comment: @Discord: С кнопкой для открытия меню всё не так очевидно. Поэтому, кстати, она и не меняет своё изображение полностью, только мелкий визуальный аспект. Аналогия не катит :)

Comment: @VladD Окей, Expander. Иконка меняется. И плюсик в TreeView.

Comment: bool _isPlaying = false;
PlayPauseButtonCommand()
{
if(!_isPlaying)
Play(); _isPlay = true;
else
Pause();  _isPlay = false;
}

Т.е. такой код я является не правильным подходом?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: С моей точки зрения — нет. Одна кнопка должна делать одно дело. Подумайте, почему вы иначе в одну команду не запихнёте ещё и удаление файла, и завершение программы.

Comment: @Discord: Плюсик, снова-таки, показывает лишь визуальное состояние. Поэтому даже то, что он развёрнут, не имеет отношения к флоу программы.

Comment: @VladD Окей. Кнопка добавления в избранное в Firefox. Она же кнопка удаления из избранного.

Comment: @Discord: А это две кнопки на месте одной, как и с play/pause. Они, понятно, взаимно-исключающие.

Comment: @VladD С чего вы взяли, что это разные кнопки? Нутром чую, что кнопка там одна, и у неё меняется только иконка.

Comment: @Discord: По поводу того, что вы нутром чуете, что в ФФ сделано так или иначе — так это ж не доказательство того, что так делать можно. У ФФ тоже есть ошибки :)